# login check in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a login form with userid and password input and login button and it is linked to a table called login in mysql with fields userid, password, category and department. the department field is used to specify departemtnt of staff. if the department field is empty, then the user is an admin. so when when i click my login button i want it to check if $department=="" and if that is true i should be redirected to admin page else my staff page. this is my checklogin.php file:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid='$myid' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION['myid'];
$_SESSION['mypassword']; 
$get=mysql_query("SELECT department FROM login");
$mydept = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
if($mydept=="")
{
header("location:admain.php");
}
else
{
header("location:stmain.php");
}
}
else
{
header("location:main_err.php");
}
```

now no matter what login id and password i give i am redirected to admain.php page can anyone help me on this??

Comment: what does print_r($result3) show?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder the `mysql_` functions are deprecated please consider using something else, especially now Before you get to comfortable with `mysql_`-functions. :)

Comment: You are not selecting the `category` field from your table.

Comment: sorry guys my mistake. i am new to php. i have now redone it. please re check question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many bugs

You are starting session later while accessing them earlier, Also you are selecting department in the query and accessing

```
$result3['category'];
```

I dont know your table structure, bug start the session at the top Replace

```
 $sql1="SELECT department FROM login WHERE id='$myid' and password='$mypassword'";
```

With

```
 $sql1="SELECT category FROM login WHERE id='$myid' and password='$mypassword'";
```

**EDIT**

Use this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid='$myid' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
  $mydept=$row['department'];
  if($mydept=="")
  {
    header("location:admain.php");
  }
  else
  {
    header("location:stmain.php");
  }
}
else
{
  header("location:main_err.php");
}
```

Comment: sorry sir it was my mistake. i have corrected the question. please re check the question.

Comment: What is department in your table login?

Comment: See the edit, I am considering department is your category also use mysqli as above, $con is your connection variable.

Comment: i dont have enough points to upvote sir sry. i similarly tried using this line in my stmain.php but dept undefined variable error.                           <font size='3'><b><marquee>WELCOME <?php session_start(); echo " ". $mydept; ?> STAFF!!</marquee></b></font>

Comment: You need to do the same in every file $mydept will not be available in other files unless you define it again

Comment: yes but how to define it without getting login id and password again and again?? i need to use the same in 3-4 different files.

Comment: 1 way is to pass variable to other page and second in to create another session variable with mydept variable

Comment: i tried using this too:     <center><h2><marquee>Welcome <?php session_start(); $result1 = $_SESSION['mydept']; echo " ". $result1; ?> Staff!! </marquee></h2></center>     but cant get still get error :/ i need help badly sir. this is very imp part of my projetc.

Comment: First Declare $_SESSION['mydept']=$mydept and then in other file access it by $result=$_SESSION['mydept'];

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with what you are doing, I don't have time to go into it all, but to answer your main question.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid='$myid' and password='$mypassword' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($results);
if($count == 1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['myid'];
    $_SESSION['mypassword']; 

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($row['category'] == "admin"){
        header("location:admain.php");
    } else {
        header("location:stmain.php");
    }
} else {
    header("location:main_err.php");
}
```

Comment: and not to forget: don't use deprecated mysql functions.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just didn't go into all the things that were going wrong with what he is doing.

Comment: WARNING: Possible SQL injection!

Comment: sir i used the ur code still getting error. please check my question again. i have updated it properly now.

Comment: sorry guys it was my mistake. new to php sorry. i have updated the question now. can u please rec check it?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple column name problem. Your first query uses "userid" and the second uses "id". I'm guessing that you should change that "id" to "userid".

If that's not it, try putting a die(mysql_error) on your queries
(e.g. $result2 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

That way, the error will be displayed in your browser.